# Questions Meteor about changing view and putting array in collection

Tags: javascript, meteor

I got two question about the Meteor framework

First of all, how can I put an array inside a Meteor collection? And how can I push values into it?

Second of all, when I have a button and I click on it, how can I change the current view? Is this by hiding and showing templates?

Thanks!

Comment: If you have two questions, please post two questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [$addToSet](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/addToSet/) to push values into an array:

```
var coll = new Meteor.Collection;
coll.insert({myArray: []});
coll.update({}, {$addToSet: {myArray: "myNewValue"}});
```

There are many ways to change views, but an easy one is to use `Session` and check whether it has a value in your template:

```
<template name="mytemplate">
  <button>Say hello</button>
  {{#if sayHello}}<p>Hello</p>{{/if}}
</template>

Template.mytemplate.events({
  "click button": function() {
    Session.set("sayHello", true);
  }
});

Template.mytemplate.sayHello = function() {
  return Session.equals("sayHello", true);
}
```

Comment: hahah thanks Rahul, what a coincidence I was one of the students in the class from last monday. Anyway, thanks!