# insert third-party api into Meteor Collection

Tags: javascript, meteor, atom-editor

I am trying to pull data from the atom.io api. I have tested with Postman and the api reports plenty of information and appears very simple, but for whatever reason, no matter what I try, i can't get this data into my Meteor Collection. My Code is:

package.js

```
Packages = new Meteor.Collection('Packages');
```

server.js

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
  if(Packages.find().count() === 0) {
    var url = "https://www.atom.io/api/packages";
    try {
        var result = HTTP.call("GET", url); //use the Synchronous version of 'GET'
        _.each(result.data, function(document) {
            Packages.insert(document);
        });
        return true;
    }
    catch (e) {
        //a network error was thrown
        console.error(e);
        return false;
    }
  }
});
```

I've checked all existing answers to my question to no avail, including the following (which have proven no help):

[Insert data to Meteor from Facebook API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20733394/insert-data-to-meteor-from-facebook-api)

[Questions Meteor about changing view and putting array in collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15278756/questions-meteor-about-changing-view-and-putting-array-in-collection)

[Meteor client subscribe to a third-party API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14678237/meteor-client-subscribe-to-a-third-party-api)

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have tried all sorts of permutations of this code (except for the right one apparently).

Comment: Where is the error ? Have you `console.log`ged your code to see if you obtain intermediate results ?

Comment: after running the code Packages.find().count() reports 0 so nothing is being pulled into the collection. I know the collection is created because I can add items to it through the JS console in the browser. But I can't get console.log to report anything of value to show why the initial run of the code is not filling the collection. Using Postman I have seen it should be a simple 'GET' (no headers, params, etc necessary) to access the API. Can't figure out if it's a problem connecting to the API or putting the API output into my collection.

Comment: I think this may be caused by periods (".") in some of the sub-keys returned by the HTTP request. Also, the _.each iterator is expecting a list, while the HTTP response seems to be an object.